# Category in home page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I'm a beginner with editing wordpress / woocommerce themes.
I have a problem with categories, I would like to set 5 categories in line not 4 + 1.

Theme installed: Storefront Version: 3.9.1

[image]

I kindly ask you to explain step by step where to make the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this question its related with programming.

Just add "5" into the Category settings (Products by Row).

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited as you told me, but the categories are listed down, adding content to the page.

As settings on woocommerce shop page I inserted a new home page and or created several blocks and also added Shortcode: [product_categories number = "5" parent = "0"] but the modification does not change.